# Ubuntu Disks: Taking too long to resize partition

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

I have 2TB external HDD which has 1TB data and 1TB free. It has only one partition. I wanted to create a new partition. So I went into Disks app -> chose my external HDD -> clicked settings icon -> resize -> drag the slider to 1.2TB from 2TB (so that I can then alloacate the free space to create my new partition) -> I clicked Ok.

It froze my disks app. I'm able to use other apps though. It's been 5 minutes. And its still frozen. I'm afraid to terminate Disks app by force (killing the process or rebooting machine) whether it will corrupt my external HDD.

Why it takes so much time? What should I do?

OS : Ubuntu 20

Update:

I ended the Disks process anyway after 10 mins. The files are safe but I'm not able to partition it still. I tried with gparted also.

[gparted_detail.htm](https://paste.ee/p/1iDfk) it let me save after the error for debugging purpose.

Comment: Was it mounted?

Comment: Yes. That might be the cause?

Comment: You can't manipulate an active partition... it would be like standing on a tree branch, and sawing it off by the trunk.

Comment: Afterwards, I tried it with the disk unmounted. Still the same. Now running "chkdsk /f" in windows as the gparted_detail.html suggessted. It's running for more than an hour.